# What is meant by "give pattern of a regular expression"

Tags: formal-languages, terminology, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I have an alphabet $A = \{b,B\}$ and I'm asked to write down the **pattern** of the regular expression $(\epsilon|bb|b)(B|bb)(b|\epsilon|b)$. What does the question actually want me to do? I'm not sure. Does it want me to give the possible patterns that can be formed with $b$ and $B$? But then surely the question would not have been phrased the way it is.

I'm just confused about what I need to do here and what is expected of the answer. If anyone could give an example it would be very helpful.

Note: This is not the original question, I changed and simplified it.

Comment: Maybe you simplified away the essence?

Comment: @Raphael - I'm sure I didn't. The only problem that I'm having is to understand what is meant by giving the pattern. Knowing the alphabet and the regular expression. For instance is it to give the pattern where b and B are concatenated? and how many patterns you can create with that for example , bBb, bB etc ?

Comment: Maybe `['B', 'Bb', 'bB', 'bBb', 'bb', 'bbB', 'bbBb', 'bbb', 'bbbb', 'bbbbb']`?

Comment: @PålGD That would be the language; I have not encountered 'pattern' as a synonym. There *are* pattern languages, though, but none of them can be generated by this regular expression

Comment: If it is an exercise, ask the person who compiled the exercise. 'Pattern' is overloaded heavily, so we have little chance of guessing what is meant.

Comment: @Raphael We don't know the context of the exercises.  Maybe the exercise is "Give patterns of the following ... ", and then this is some sub-exercise, which happens to be a finite language.  In any way, I would vote to close this question as we obviously do not have enough to answer anything besides what I said in my previous comment.

Comment: I would think the task is to simplify the expression. It is regular expression, but it can be made simpler by using (some of) the regular expression operators like $x^*$, $x^+$, $x^?$ and $x^{m,n}$ (in addition to the two already used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **pattern** (in the context of languages and automata) is a way of defining a set of strings. A string matches a pattern if it belongs in the set defined by that pattern. So, your regular expression is actually a pattern. The question, I think, would be to find the pattern given a set of strings!

Comment: Well, the problem is that what is given _is_ a regular expression pattern. But it's somewhat convoluted, so it should apparently be simplified.